# Work on Windows - build on linux and docker

Tags: linux, eclipse, docker, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that want to build inside a docker on a linux machine.
So my setup is that I have the Eclipse CDT IDE installed on my Windows machine, and I have my source code on my machine as well.
And then I have my linux machine-server where I have my Docker with different images and containers. As of until now I have run Eclipse on my Linux machine remotely, but this is slow.

I now want to use the IDE installed on my windows. I have connected to my Linux machine and found the same container that I used before.

BUT now comes my problem. I get this error.
Error Copy Volumes.

I don't understand this.

I want to copy the source code and libs to the container, how is this done?

Sorry the confusing meassage, but thanks for helping.

BR Ragnar

Comment: It is most correctly done with a `COPY` directive inside the Dockerfile.  Docker volumes are not part of it, and your Dockerfile can't build an image out of code that will be injected only when the built image is run.